# Excel: Dividing a Number with Greater Than Symbol and Less Than Symbol (i.e. >15/5, <20/5, >20/5)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, operators, division

Imagine A1 is a cell that I put numbers in and A2 is a cell that will automatically give the vaule of A1 divided by 5.

```
=A1/5
```

But when I enter a number to A1 with a greater than symbol (>) or a less than symbol (<) such as >15, A2 gives #VALUE! instead of >3. Is there a way to code this please?

Comment: Something like `=IF(N(A1),A1/5,LEFT(A1)&MID(A1,2,99)/5)`?

Comment: Thanks, although I have no idea what's happening, but this will do!

Comment: Ok, I'll post as an answer and you can accept.

Comment: While we are at it, is there a way to make the result have less decimal places?

Comment: Can you clarify with an example?

Comment: So the number I am dividing is 38.67, when I enter <10, it gives <0.258598396689941 mmol/L. Is there a way to round it to the first decimal place so it gives <0.2 or <0.3 which ever is easier?

Comment: Nevermind, I did it with the round function, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment yet but I'd like to add an explanation to [Jos Woolley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74051915/20205391)

`=IF(N(A1),A1/5,LEFT(A1)&MID(A1,2,99)/5)`

`N(A1)` Is using the property of the `N` function to check if the value in `A1` is a number or, in your case, a number with an operator in front of it. If the value of `A1` is a whole number, `A1/5` is produced, and if `A1` has an operator (</>) then `LEFT(A1)&MID(A1,2,99)/5` will be produced.

The `LEFT(text, [num_chars])` function takes a cell value and recreates that cell, from the left, for a total number of characters put into the function in the `[num_chars]` parameter. If no parameter is set, the single leftmost character will be used, in you case, it will be `<` or `>`.

`&` is used to string together calculated cells, and in this case is being used to take the `<` or `>` from the `LEFT` function and adding the `MID` function to it.

The `MID` function is like the `LEFT` function, only you can choose the starting character, rather than start at the beginning of the string. What's happening in `MID(A1,2,99)` is taking the value in `A1`, for example `>15`, and starting at the second character, recreates the next 99 characters. This means as long as the number you're using to divide is 99 digits long or less, this formula will work fine. This value is then divided by 5.

I hope that's a good enough explanation, since you said you didn't understand what it meant at first. Glad that it works for you!

Also, because of your comment, I'm assuming it looks something more like

`=IF(N(A1),A1/5,LEFT(A1)&ROUND(MID(A1,2,99)/5,1))`

Which would indeed get you your result :)

Comment: Very kind of you to take the time to add such a detailed explanation of my answer, thanks.

Comment: My sincere thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(N(A1),A1/5,LEFT(A1)&MID(A1,2,99)/5)`